# MySQL CONCAT returns incorrect result when used with variable in Dbeaver

Tags: mysql, sql, string-concatenation, dbeaver

Is there any known issue about using variables in CONCAT or am I making a mistake in below query?

```
set @m := '2016';
select concat('2015','-',@m);
```

Expected result is 2015-2016, but strangely it returns

```
2015F201
```

I tested many other variations with and without using variables, it works as expected without variables, but return similiar 'unexpected' results when used with variables.

Comment: I get '2015-2016', which version and platform are you using?

Comment: My version is 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2

Comment: It works for me as well, even playing around with different default collations.

Comment: Very strange, I've been trying several hours with no luck :(

Comment: Are the ones upvoting the question confirming that they are running through the same issue?

Comment: Make sure you run this from a clean mysql client.

Comment: I just tested on 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, it works as expected. I'll test using another client as suggested by Vatev.

Comment: Yes, it IS a client side problem, I'm using DBeaver as SQL Client (which is normally a very nice application), it somehow tries to show the result of that query as binary (hence hexadecimal).

Comment: Should I answer my own question as above? Or just leave it as it is?
By the way I found an option to "show binary values as string" in DBeaver, so it can show as expected.
Thank you everyone for lead me to right direction.

Comment: Ok I did, thank you. I can accept it as answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using DBeaver as SQL client, it somehow thinks that the result of that query is binary:

```
select concat('2015','-',@m);
```

and show it incorrectly: 2015F201 (not exactly hexadecimal)

When I change settings under Preferences window, Common / Result Sets / Binaries / Binary Data formatter to String, it shows correctly.